# Cordova Android iframe Java exception was raised during method invocation

Tags: java, android, cordova, exception, iframe

The problem was simple, whenever I added to my Cordova app's HTML an `<iframe>`, I couldn't use the cordova API. The deviceready event has never got fired. If I tried to use an API method, e.g. the inappbrowser to open an URL in external browser, I've received the following exception in console:

```
Java exception was raised during method invocation
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure what was the core issue, I did some searching and perhaps Cordova can't handle multiple simultaneous api pipes at once on Android (from both the main page and the iframe). Someone might explain better or find the actual problem.

What helped me was removing the `<iframe>` from HTML and adding it using the scripts (after cordova.js was loaded and deviceready was fired) with simple jQuery call:

```
$('body').append('<iframe id="framed" style="border: none;" src="..."></iframe>');
```

This has made the exception to not appear anymore and all cordova API calls and events work again.

Hope it helps someone.